# LINQ-запросы. Использование оператора group

Tags: c#, linq

Изучая LINQ-запросы, надумал себе следующую задачку: "Необходимо написать программу, которая будет группировать студентов по их возрасту, а потом выводить список полученных групп и студентов в них. Вывод должен представлять собой нечто следующее:

19 : Вася, Петя, Саша

21 : Миша

Пишу следующий код:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student[] array = {
        new Student("Vasya","Pupkin",20),
        new Student("Sanya","Ponomarev",21),
        new Student("Alexey","Mechkin",20),
        new Student("Vitya","Pupkin",19),
        new Student("Bashmak","Fedochenko",23)};

        var groupsByAge = from ageGroup in array
                          group ageGroup by ageGroup.Age;

        foreach (var group in groupsByAge) Console.WriteLine($"Group is 
 {group}");
   }
}
```

И класс Student

```
class Student
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Surname { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }

    public Student(string name, string surname, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

Когда произвожу вывод даже на данном этапе написания кода, результат следующий:

```
Group is System.Linq.Lookup`2+Grouping[System.Int32,SecondTestProject.Student]
Group is System.Linq.Lookup`2+Grouping[System.Int32,SecondTestProject.Student]
Group is System.Linq.Lookup`2+Grouping[System.Int32,SecondTestProject.Student]
Group is System.Linq.Lookup`2+Grouping[System.Int32,SecondTestProject.Student]
```

Хочется верить, что причину вывода такого результата я понимаю. В цикле foreach, полагаю, я вывожу что то вроде адресов этих групп (ситуация на подобии если бы я хотел вывести ссылку на объект). Однако как выполнить задачу я не знаю. Необходимо что бы цикл(ы) foreach выводили сначала группу, потом студентов которые в неё входят, а затем следующую группу.

Насколько я понимаю, запрос я сформировал правильно, но  вывод произвел неверно. Как правильно выполнить запрос и вывести результаты в необходимом мне виде?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку `group` - [это коллекция](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb344977%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), то для для "склеивания" значений этой коллекции необходимо осуществить её перебор. Сделать это можно разными способами, например - [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb549218(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine($"{group.Key}: {group.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, k) => $"{current}{(string.IsNullOrEmpty(current) ? string.Empty : ", ")}{k.Name}")}");
```

Так же можно добавить сортировку:

```
var groupsByAge = from ageGroup in array
                orderby ageGroup.Age
                group ageGroup by ageGroup.Age;
```

> 19: Vitya
>   20: Vasya, Alexey
>    21: Sanya
>   23: Bashmak

Comment: есть ли возможность пояснить данный код?  Console.WriteLine($"Group is {group.Key}: {group.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, k) => current + ", " + k.Name)}"); не понимаю. Aggregate - ясно, выполняет лямбду на каждом элементе последовательности. Но как я изучал ранее - лямбда строится на основе делегата. Где наш делегат? Что такое string.Empty, зачем он нужен? что у нас в качестве current, а что  в качестве k?

Comment: `current` - это результирующая строка на момент обращения, `k` - очередной элемент коллекции. Первый параметр - `string.Empty` - это результирующая строка (`current`) на старте. Обновил ссылку на документацию, изначально ссылка была некорректной и указывала на другую перегрузку метода `Aggregate`, без начального значения агрегатора.

Comment: @АлексейФедотов в данном случае вам нужен `Join` и не городите костыли. Пример реализации смотрите в моем ответе.

Comment: @PavelMayorov замечание справедливое, но извольте выбирать выражения. Дело было 5 лет назад, на тот момент я не видел проблем предложить этот вариант в качестве ответа на конкретный вопрос с конкретными данными. Плюс в ответе есть оговорка, что *сделать это можно разными способами*. К слову, `Aggregate` может принимать `StringBuilder` и не отличается от `string.Join` в этом случае

Comment: Передача в Aggregate нечистой функции - тоже нехорошо

Answer (score 3):

```
Console.WriteLine($"{group.Key} : {string.Join(", ", group.Select(s => s.Name))}");
```

Так же я рекомендую юзать LINQ через экстеншены:

```
var groupsByAge = array.GroupBy(s => s.Age);
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо было просто вывести двумя Циклами примерно

```
foreach ( var group in groupsByAge )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(group.Key+" : ");
            foreach ( var student in group) {

                Console.WriteLine(student.Name);
            }
         так как первый цикл работает с группами, а второй внутри property
```